# Landsat imagery showing up as white in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, folium

I am trying to learn GEE's Python API through Google Colab.  Right now I am trying to map Landsat using folium and geehydro.  I was able to implement NDVI just fine, and it displayed exactly as I intended, but now I am having trouble figuring out the best way to display the bands to show RGB. Here's the code I have so far, it isn't working as intended-- it just shows a white tile.

```
import ee
import geemap
import geehydro
import folium
ee.Authenticate()
ee.Initialize(project='ee-xyzzy')

#Dates for imagery acquisition
i_date = '2020-01-01'
f_date = '2020-12-30'

#AOI point in Alabama
my_AOI = ee.Geometry.Point([-87, 33])

#Fetching Landsat 8 RGB as ee Image Collection for 2020
landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2").filterDate(i_date,f_date).filterBounds(my_AOI).min()

#Starts the map at the right location.
Map = folium.Map(location=[33,-87],zoom_start=8)

#Corresponding bands for L8
red = landsat.select("SR_B4")
green = landsat.select("SR_B3")
blue = landsat.select("SR_B2")

#Do RGB parameters work like this to display bands?  This is where I'm confused
rgb_params = {'bands': ['SR_B5','SR_B4','SR_B3'],
              'min': 0,
              'max': 0.3}

Map.addLayer(landsat,rgb_params, 'RGB Image')
Map
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two issues.

The first is that the code you included isn't working because `folium.Map.addLayer` is not a real method. I think you're mixing that up with `geemap.Map.addLayer`, which is the [recommended solution](https://medium.com/google-earth/python-powers-up-the-rise-of-the-python-api-for-earth-engine-056741eb1b75) for viewing Earth Engine data in Python. Using the code below will allow you to use the `addLayer` method with your image.

```py
Map = geemap.Map(center=[33, -87], zoom=8)
```

The second problem is that the minimum and maximum values you define in `rgb_params` are much smaller than the scaled and offset Landsat pixel values, causing the image to appear white. You *could* fix this by changing the `min` and `max` to roughly `7000` and `25000`, respectively, but if you plan to do any analysis or use vegetation indices you should undo the scale and offset instead.

Landsat images in Earth Engine are stored with their values [scaled and offset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2#bands) to reduce storage space. As shown in the [official example](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C02_T1_L2#colab-python) for this collection, you can undo the scale and offset by multiplying and adding a constant value to each image. Here's your code, modified to include the scaling.

```py
# Applies scaling factors.
def apply_scale_factors(image):
  optical_bands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2)
  thermal_bands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0)
  return image.addBands(optical_bands, None, True).addBands(
      thermal_bands, None, True
  )

#Fetching Landsat 8 RGB as ee Image Collection for 2020
landsat = (
    ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
    .filterDate(i_date,f_date)
    .filterBounds(my_AOI)
    # Adjust each image in the collection to the correct range
    .map(apply_scale_factors)
    .min()
)
```

Now, the `rgb_params` you originally defined should be in the correct range and your image should appear as expected.